# RelaxNG: a list pattern must not contain an element pattern (list//ref)

Tags: xml, relaxng

I am trying to make a list of different publications(book,article, collection) in relaxNG, but when I try to use the list tag it gives an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar
    xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
    xmlns:a="http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0"
    datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">  

  <start>
    <element name="publications">
      <oneOrMore>
        <interleave>
          <list>
            <choice>
              <element name="article">
                <element name="publication_name">
                  <text/>
                </element>
                <element name="authors">
                  <text/>
                </element>
                <element name="publisher">
                  <text/>
                </element>
                <element name="volume">
                  <data
                      datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
                      type="int"/>
                </element>
                <element name="number">
                  <data
                      datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
                      type="int"/>
                </element>
                <element name="pages">
                  <data
                      datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
                      type="int"/>
                </element>
                <element name="citation">
                  <data
                      datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
                      type="int"/>
                </element>
                <element name="year">
                  <data
                      datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
                      type="int"/>
                </element>
              </element>
              <element name="book">
                <element name="publication_name">
                  <text/>
                </element>
                <element name="authors">
                  <text/>
                </element>

                <element name="publisher">
                  <text/>
                </element>
                <element name="citation">
                  <data
                      datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
                      type="int"/>
                </element>
                <element name="year">
                  <data
                      datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
                      type="int"/>
                </element>
              </element>
              <element name="chapter">
                <element name="publication_name">
                  <text/>
                </element>
                <element name="authors">
                  <text/>
                </element>
                <element name="collection_name">
                  <text/>
                </element>
                <element name="editors">
                  <text/>
                </element>
                <element name="citation">
                  <data
                      datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
                      type="int"/>
                </element>
                <element name="year">
                  <data
                      datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
                      type="int"/>
                </element>
              </element>
            </choice>                       
          </list>
        </interleave>
      </oneOrMore>
    </element>
  </start>
</grammar>
```

I want to be able to divide the publications in the three categories.

The error I am getting is:

> a list pattern must not contain an element pattern (section 7.1 of the
>   RELAX NG specification requires that the simplified XML form of the 
>   schema not contain any elements matching the path list//ref)

Answer (score 1):

See the rule 4.19 in the [RelaxNG Specification](http://relaxng.org/spec-20011203.html). It replaces the elements by refs to newly created definitions, but `list//ref` is forbidden (as the error says, see 7.1 in the beforementioned spec).